# Scaling an NSView to print full screen without margins

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

I'm trying to get my NSView to print full screen without any margins but I'm not having much luck. I have set the margins to 0 and scaled the view as high as it will go without spilling over into a second page but it won't go beyond about a cm from the edge, and more at the bottom. Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (void)printThis:(id)sender{
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
[printInfo setTopMargin:0];
[printInfo setBottomMargin:0];
[printInfo setLeftMargin:0];
[printInfo setRightMargin:0];
[printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:YES];
[printInfo setVerticallyCentered:YES];
[printInfo setScalingFactor:1.318];
[[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self] runOperation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out by using the 'set paper size' method to set the paper size to be equal to A4 using the code:

```
NSSize a4;
a4.width = 210;
a4.height = 297;
```